# Room Migration?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, android-architecture-components

Shall we describe all fields of a new table while migration from version `X` to `X+1` like it is shown in the doc:

```
static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
@Override
public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE `Fruit` (`id` INTEGER, "
            + "`name` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))");
}
};
```

If so, how describe `migration` for the `class` with `Embedded` annotation with nested `Embedded` annotation?

```
public class DirectorsStaff {
private String secretKey;
@Embedded
private DirectorsAnswer directorsAnswer;

public String getSecretKey() {
    return secretKey;
}

public void setSecretKey(String secretKey) {
    this.secretKey = secretKey;
}

public DirectorsAnswer getDirectorsAnswer() {
    return directorsAnswer;
}

public void setDirectorsAnswer(DirectorsAnswer directorsAnswer) {
    this.directorsAnswer = directorsAnswer;
}
}
```

`DirectorsStaff` is also `Embedded`

Answer (score 3):

Using `@Embedded` to annotate a field of an **entity / pojo** will actually create such subfields in the table.

`Room` just does you a favor to assemble them to a specific type whenever you do a query having such subfields.

Therefore you should describe all fields of a new table while migration.

---

Suppose the database has a `Foo` table for version 1 and you want to add a new table `Bar` for version 2.

```kotlin
@Entity
data class Foo(
  @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
  val name: String
)

@Entity
data class Bar(
  @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
  @Embedded(prefix = "foo_") val foo: Foo
)

class Migration1_2: Migration(1, 2) {
  override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
     database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Bar (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, foo_id INTEGER NOT NULL, foo_name TEXT NOT NULL)")
  }
}
```

Comment: I have found the same in the doc, but I still cannot such upgrade. Can you write a piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

`migrate()` should run `ALTER TABLE` (it's the main purpose, where one does not have to describe whole tables, but only describes the fields or indexes, which shall be altered), as well as occasionally it might contain a `CREATE TABLE` or a `DROP TABLE` statement. what you've annotated as `@Embedded`, that should be another Room entity (this barely influences the migration, but the mapping).

Comment: Martin, thank you for the answer,  but I can't find your explanation clear. Can you provide more details? I know the difference between alter, create, drop, I am wondering why it is still so painful to upgrade your DB? What if have first update with 2 tables and my next application update I have 12 additional tables? Shall my migration instance contain all their fields? 

As far as I understand from the documentation I can omit `entity` annotation for embedded objects, but which code I need to have for such migration?

Comment: @IgorSkryl you probably should read the docs: https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html ...and in order to migrate properly, use https://www.sqlite.org/sqldiff.html (so that the script to migrate in between revisions cannot miss out on relevant alternations). Room basically has little to do with the migrations; because one manipulates an existing database, so that it still matches the updated Room abstraction layer of it. when being required to add new tables, these are of course complete table-creation queries, including all of the fields and indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `ColumnInfo`, then you can directly reference that column

```
@Entity
data class Foo(
  @ColumnInfo(name = "foo_id") val id: Int,
  @ColumnInfo(name = "foo_name") val name: String
)

@Entity
data class Bar(
  @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
  @Embedded val foo: Foo
)

class Migration1_2: Migration(1, 2) {
  override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
     database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Bar (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, foo_id INTEGER NOT NULL, foo_name TEXT NOT NULL)")
  }
}
```